# Bitbucket Pipelines - AWSCLI - ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement botocore==1.29.21 (from awscli)

Tags: pip, bitbucket, aws-cli, pypi, bitbucket-pipelines

Today we have faced an specific error about a dependency of aws cli called botocore.
We are using pip from a bitbucket caches like in this yml below:

```
    - step: &build-and-publish
          name: Build and Publish
          services:
            - docker
          caches:
            - pip
          script:
            - pip3 install awscli
```

During the building process, the following error happens: **ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement botocore==1.29.21 (from awscli)** .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our Solution was to upgrade pip using this code in the bitbucket-pipelines.yml file: **pip install --upgrade pip** .

The final bitbucket-pipelines.yml:

```
 - step: &build-and-publish
              name: Build and Publish
              services:
                - docker
              caches:
                - pip
              script:
                - pip install --upgrade pip  
                - pip3 install awscli
```

We don't know if it's a bug on Bitbucket Pipelines or something wrong with our project. We are still investigating it. But maybe this solution can be helpful if it's a bug.

Comment: Could you detail what pip version were you using before and after the update?

Comment: I couldn't find a place to set the version of the pre-defined cache in bitbucket documentation.
That was ther previous version: 
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.3; however, version 22.3.1 is available.

Answer (score 0):

awscli 1.27.21 depending on botocore 1.29.21 were simultaneously published (uploaded to pypi.org) yesterday around 20:16 UTC.

My guess is there is a small time window with non-zero chance of pypi.org not having consistently distributed this info globally yet.

Just try again now.

Comment: thank you for for this. We've solved it running manually a pip upgrade.